# Change the default boot options for ubuntu desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I have recently installed Unbuntu Desktop 10.10 on a partition alongside my normal Windows 7 x64 install. I expected to have only one OS boot menu which I would be able to edit via msconfig.exe in Windows. However I have two seperate sets of boot menus.

The first one contains a bunch of different Ubuntu boot options and also contains an option to boot to Windows 7 (this is last in the list).

If I choose windows 7 then I get presented with a second boot menu containing two options:

- Windows 7
- Ubuntu

The first boot menu defaults to Ubuntu and is on a short timeout. I want to change this to default to Windows 7 and increase the timeout. Can anyone help?

Google tells me to edit /boot/grub/menu.lst and although I do have a grub folder 
I don't seem to have a file called menu.lst: [Change default operating system at boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/6.10/ubuntu/desktopguide/C/ch10s05.html)

I'm an Ubuntu and Linux n00b so please be gentle with any answers.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu starting with 9.10 uses Grub 2. Grub 2 uses `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` instead of `menu.lst`, but you make changes in `/etc/default/grub` and use `update-grub` or `update-grub2` to update it. Please see [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275) for more information.

Change these settings:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

To something like:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows 7"
GRUB_TIMEOUT=20
```

Where you'd substitute the actual name of the Windows 7 menu entry.

You can remove Ubuntu from the second menu by starting a Window CMD shell (after you've booted Windows) and running:

```
bcdedit /delete Ubuntu
```

Comment: hmm... that didn't work.

Comment: I tried changing the entry to

Comment: GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows 7" and I also tried changing it to GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows 7 (loader) (on dev/sda1)" which is the exact text in the menu

Comment: I also tried changing it to GRUB_DEFAULT=6 as it's the 7th entry in the list but this also had no effect, it just boots into Unbuntu after the timeout

Comment: @SpookyAction: According the information that I linked to, you can use a text string to name a menu item.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Ah, your right, I hadn't realized Grub2 supported using a menu item's name. I'm deleting my previous comment as to not confuse people.